# DOJO include files a directory back

Tags: javascript, include-path, dojo

I have dojo files in `resources/js/dojo1.6/dojo/dojo.js`

I have another file here `resources/js/pages/file1.js`

This file requires another file which is located at `resources/js/folder/file2.js`

This is how I am including it `dojo.require('folder.file2');`

So these three folder are in hirarchy

**dojo1.6**, **pages** and **folder**

When I run application

I got the following error

```
File not found: /resources/js/dojo1.6/folder/file2.js
```

How can I overcome this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Dojo where your modules can be found, relative to dojo.js, using `dojo.registerModulePath`:

```
dojo.registerModulePath("pages", "../../pages");
dojo.registerModulePath("folder", "../../folder");
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/registerModulePath.html for a more detailed explanation.